# How to calculate the length of an element of a list by Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I already have the following code:

```
"atom_length(Var, Len) :- length(Var, Len)."
```

I wanna construct a predicate atom_lengths/2 that does the same thing with a list of atoms:

```
?-  atom_lengths([one, two, three, four], [3, 3, 5, 4]).
true.
?-  atom_lengths([one, two, three, four], LS).
LS = [3, 3, 5, 4].
?-  atom_lengths([], LS).
LS = [].
```

How to write "atom_lengths"??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `length/2` to compute the length of an atom.
You can however first convert each atom to a list of characters with `atom_chars/2` and then use `length/2` to get its length:

```
atom_lengths([], []).
atom_lengths([Atom|Atoms], [Length|LAtoms]):-
  atom_chars(Atom, L),
  length(L, Length),
  atom_lengths(Atoms, LAtoms).
```

Test:

```
?- atom_lengths([one, two, three, four], LS).

LS = [3,3,5,4]
```

Instead of using the pair `atom_chars/2-length/2` you could also use ISO builtin predicate `atom_length/2`:

```
atom_lengths([], []).
atom_lengths([Atom|Atoms], [Length|LAtoms]):-
  atom_length(Atom, Length),
  atom_lengths(Atoms, LAtoms).
```

or using `findall/3`:

```
atom_lengths(Atoms, LAtoms):-
  findall(Length, (member(Atom, Atoms), atom_length(Atom, Length)), LAtoms).
```

As suggested by commenter, a better idiom would be to use `maplist/3`:

```
atom_lengths(Atoms, LAtoms):-
  maplist(atom_length, Atoms LAtoms).
```

Comment: findall isn't the correct idiom here, maplist would be better.

Comment: @Mog: Right!. Improved answer

Answer (score 2):

Using `maplist` + `atom_length`:

```
?- maplist(atom_length, [one, two, three, four], [3, 3, 5, 4]).
true.

?- maplist(atom_length, [one, two, three, four], Ls).
Ls = [3, 3, 5, 4].

?- maplist(atom_length, [], Ls).
Ls = [].
```